compiler:testCompile puts all transitive dependencies on module path
I added a module.info to my src/main/java and then also to my src/test/java, as per the example here. Compiling my main code is no problem. I see the compiler:compile goal adds only my direct (non-transitive) dependencies to the module path (most of them as automatic modules), and the rest to the class path, which is great as that means I only have to deal with modularity issues in my direct dependencies. Compiling the test code, however, fails with multiple errors about split packages. It turns out the compiler:testCompile goal puts all my dependencies on the module path, even the transitive ones, where these split package issues reside.
Why does the Maven Compiler Plugin treat the test code so differently from production code? Is there a way to make the compiler:testCompile goal resolve the module path in the same way as the compiler:compile goal?
More detail:
Relevant pom snippet:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

module.info in src/main/java:
module org.yonas.project {
    exports services;
    requires swagger.parser.core;
    requires swagger.parser;
    requires io.swagger.v3.oas.models;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml;
}

module.info in src/test/java:
open module org.yonas.project.test {
    exports testpackage;
    requires org.yonas.project;
    requires transitive org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires transitive org.junit.jupiter.engine;
    requires java.net.http;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires swagger.parser.core;
    requires swagger.parser;
    requires io.swagger.v3.oas.models;
    requires org.assertj.core;
}

Running mvn compile -X returns (among many other things):
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[a lot of jars here, including transitive dependencies]

[DEBUG] Modulepath:
[a few jars here, only direct dependencies]

Running mvn test -X returns (among many other things):
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG] Modulepath:
[many jars here]

[...]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project ...
failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] the unnamed module reads package com.github.fge.jackson from both jackson.coreutils.equivalence and jackson.coreutils
[ERROR] the unnamed module reads package io.swagger.parser from both swagger.compat.spec.parser and swagger.parser
[ERROR] ...
[...and 97 more errors concerning split packages]

I tried removing the module.info from src/test/java, but that leads to new issues as I'm using libraries and modules in my test code that I don't use in the production code. I've seen people recommend adding a requires static to the main module.info for those modules, but I'm not a fan of this approach as it makes the production module 'aware' of the test code. Also, for unit tests I guess I don't really care about modules, but for my integration tests I'd like to treat my production code as a modularized library, so it wouldn't make sense to leave out the module.info from src/test/java in that case. The latter is also the reason I'd rather not set the <useModulePath> flags to false in the compiler and surefire configuration.
